# cmd.exe closes instantly when running batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a simple batch file that will let me pick from a list of programs and run them based on my choice. For reference this is what I have so far:

```
@echo off 
:menu
echo 1. zsnes
echo 2. Project64
echo 3. MAME
echo 4. PCSX2
echo 5. VBA
echo 6. DOSBox
set /p emu=Pick your emulator [1-6]:
if %emu%=1 goto zsnes
if %emu%=2 goto project64
if %emu%=3 goto mame
if %emu%=4 goto pcsx2
if %emu%=5 goto vba
if %emu%=6 goto dosbox
:zsnes
start /d "C:\Users\*username*\Documents\zsnes\" zsnesw.exe
```

I've just typed out through the zsnes program to test it. The command prompt launches and will ask for me to pick a choice. When I select 1, cmd.exe instantly closes but the program is not run. I made a script that contained only the start line and it worked fine. When I open cmd.exe manually and type that line in it also works fine. It just doesn't work in the context of my script. What could be causing this? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest you start reading the help file for commands before you use them.  You would have seen your SYNTAX error immediately. Also you need to learn to debug your own batch file.  Turn ECHO ON and run the batch file from the cmd prompt.  This way you will see the error when it happens because the cmd.exe session you have open will not terminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your if is not correct .

Try with

```
if %emu% == 1 goto zsnes
```

or

```
 if %emu% equ 1 goto zsnes
```

and so on.

Some syntax errors in `IF` and `FOR` commands leads force exist of the script.

probably you'll want also

```
:zsnes
start /d "C:\Users\*username*\Documents\zsnes\" zsnesw.exe
goto :eof
```

to avoid executuion of the code under the other labels.

Comment: Wow, that did it! I feel silly for missing such a simple thing as a proper equality check. This is the first time I'm trying to use a batch script for something practical, so yeah. Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

write the following line at the end of the code or where you want to stop / pause your cmd.exe

```
timeout \t -1
```

this will pause your cmd screen and give you an option to close it by asking Yes/No ?.

Comment: `pause` or `timeout`at the end of the script won't help, because the script don't reach this command, when it  crashes with a syntax error before. Best for Troubleshooting is not to start it by double-clicking, but from executing it manally from a cmd-window (preferably with `@echo on`)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like the one before me said, "if" should be:

```
    if %emu% == 1 goto zsnes
```

Additionally, add "pause" after your batch, so you can read the error-messages when something fails.

Comment: `pause` or `timeout`at the end of the script won't help, because the script don't reach this command, when it  crashes with a syntax error before. Best for Troubleshooting is not to start it by double-clicking, but from executing it manally from a cmd-window (preferably with `@echo on`)